# Sql insertion error through php

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting an error message when I try to insert values in a sql table via php coding. Even I also create a new database again but it's not working. So I need your help to solve it. My error message is given below:

> Insertion failed! You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use
>   near'Usage,Validity,Price)values('indranil','som','WWBIPL_NE_4GB','512kbps','4GB','3'
>   at line 1

My html code is given below :

```
<html>
<head>
<body>
<form action="insert.php" method="post">
<select name="package">
<option value="WWBIPL_NE_4GB">WWBIPL_NE_4GB</option>
<option value="WWBIPL_NE_6GB">WWBIPL_NE_6GB</option>
</select>
Firstname:<input type="text" name="firstname">
Lastname:<input type="text" name="secondname">
Email:<input type="text" name="email">
Address:<input type="text" name="address">
<input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</head>
</html>
```

Here is my PHP code

```
<?php
$fstname=$_POST["firstname"];
$sndname=$_POST["secondname"];
$price=$_POST["package"];
if($price=="WWBIPL_NE_4GB")
{
$bandwidth="512kbps";
$usage="4GB";
$validity="30days";
$price1="499";
}
else if($price=="WWBIPL_NE_6GB")
{
$bandwidth="512kbps";
$usage="6GB";
$validity="90days";
$price1="1280";
}
$servername="localhost";
$username="root";
$password="";
$dbname="stock";
$conn=mysqli_connect($servername,$username,$password,$dbname);
if(!$conn)
{
die("Connection Failed".mysqli_error($conn));
}   $sql="insertintoisuue(Firstname,Lastname,Package,Bandwidth,Usage,Validity,Price)values('$fstname','$sndname','$price','$bandwidth','$usage','$validity','$price1')";
if(mysqli_query($conn,$sql))
{
echo"Data inserted successfully";
}
else
{
echo"Insertion failed".mysqli_error($conn);
}
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: AFAIK, `insertintoisuue` would work better written this way: `insert into isuue`. Apart from that, your SQL is wide open to injections.

Comment: I already did.. It is a printing mistake

Answer (score 3):

`Usage` is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html) in mysql . You havr to escape it with backticks or better rename your column

```
$sql="insert into isuue(Firstname,Lastname,Package,Bandwidth,`Usage`,Validity,Price)values('$fstname','$sndname','$price','$bandwidth','$usage','$validity','$price1')";
```

Alo you should use prepared statements and of cause as X.L.Ant mentioned you should write `insert into ...` with blanks.

Comment: sory it was printing mistake..I already wrote  insert into                                isuue(Firstname,Lastname,Package,Bandwidth,`Usage`,Validity,Price)values('$fstname','$sndname','$price','$bandwidth','$usage','$validity','$price1')";   with spaces

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
$sql="insertintoisuue(Firstname,Lastname,Package,Bandwidth,Usage,Validity,Price)values('$fstname','$sndname','$price','$bandwidth','$usage','$validity','$price1')";
```

with:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO isuue (Firstname, Lastname, Package, Bandwidth, Usage,
          Validity, Price ) 
      VALUES ('$fstname', '$sndname',' $price','$bandwidth',  
          $usage','$validity','$price1')";
```